# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord what does .anything do after a find?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following Code:

```
@contacts = Project.find(params[:project_id].to_i).contacts
```

Can someone explain me what does `.contacts` part do at the end of this line? I try to figure out, but i can't find a answer. I think it must be something like a include or something, but I really don't understand. Would be really happy for any advise (maybe only a link to a explanation would be enough. I tried to find something but i don't know what i've to search because i've no idea what this is..)

Comment: make sure to select an answer, that fits best to your question and checkmark it. This way you let other users know, your issue is solved.

Answer (score 4):

`.contacts` method returns a collection of `Contact` objects associated with your `Project` model.

You must have a `has_many :contacts` relationship defined there on your `Project` model ( `app/models/project.rb` ) and `belongs_to :project` on your `Contact` model ( `app/models/contact.rb` ).

This association is an activerecord abstraction for the relationship between the `projects` and `contacts` table on your database which means that a row on `projects` table (i.e a `Project` object) can have many contacts (i.e many rows on `contacts` table) based on a foreign key `project_id` on the `contacts` table.

In the code, `@contacts = Project.find(params[:project_id].to_i).contacts` , the `find` method returns a single object (`Project` model) from your `projects` table with the value of column `id` passed as `params[:project_id]`. Then `.contacts` returns all the associated rows from the `contacts` table (rows with value of `project_id` equal to `params[:project_id].to_i`).

In a single table rails activerecord operation, The following line gives the same list of rows from `contacts` table with column `project_id` having value `params[:project_id].to_i` as the line in your question.

```
@contacts = Contact.where(project_id: params[:project_id].to_i)
```

This returns all rows in `contacts` table having the value of `project_id` column equal to `params[:project_id].to_i`.

rails has excellent documentations on [activerecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [active record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 2):

You [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) a single project object with

```
Project.find(params[:project_id].to_i) # returns a Project instance
```

and then get its associated `contacts`.

It is equivalent to

```
project = Project.find(params[:project_id].to_i) # btw `find` accepts strings as well, so no need for `to_i`
project.contacts
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i understand a bit more. :P Still to complex to understand what the whole programm is doing, but thats the reason why i want to learn it!
And thx for the advise with de to_i, but i think its not bad to do it? This Code is part of a API, is there not a danger for SQL injections when i don't put this to_i ?

Comment: @Twinfriends you're welcome! It's not bad to convert `params[:project_id]` it to integer. As to SQL injection - since `find` method takes either string or integer and constructs a query like `SELECT  projects.* FROM projects WHERE projects.id = $1` I think it is not vulnerable to injection, but in general you are right to want to sanitize incoming params :)

Answer (score 0):

in your question `contacts` is a method that is being called on the result of a method that was called on another object

In this case it is sending a message `contacts` to the ActiveRecord object that is returned from the `find` method called on the `Project` class

Whether or not that result is able to respond to that message is not as straightforward as you think. You often get errors like this in ruby:

```
undefined method `contacts' for nil:NilClass
```

However, that is not likely not happen in this case because the `find` method raises an exception if it cannot find the record (whereas `find_by` returns nil)

Remember that in ruby everything is an object and method calls can be chained